# ESLint claims dataTransfer.setData is typed 'any'

Tags: javascript, typescript, drag-and-drop, eslint, data-transfer

I'm coding a drag and drop feature in TypeScript, but for some reason TS throws on me that when calling e.dataTransfer.setData() it is typed 'any', however when I hover over it shows me a correct type declaration.

```
...
    if (!(e.target instanceof HTMLLIElement)) return;
    if (e.dataTransfer.setData) {
      e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', '123'); // Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.
    }
...
```

[correct type declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c7Hi.png)

Is there any *right* way of doing this?

Comment: `HTMLLIElement` a typo? Shouldn't it be `HTMLElement`?

Comment: It's a <li> element I'm listening on, the check is mainly because TS would shout about e.target.dataset being possible null.